# Ionic 3 IOS App does not work for first launch, but works after force kill and launch

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an IOS app using IONIC.

**When I first launch the App in simulator or real device, the app is stuck on splash screen**. Platform ready event is never getting called and thus splashscreen is never hidden. But it works fine after I kill the app and launch again. No idea which direction should I look in. Here is my ionic info

@ionic/cli-utils  : 2.0.0-rc.6
   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.0.0-rc.6

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
   Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
   NodeJS            : v8.9.1
   npm               : 6.0.0
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 9.4 Build version 9F1027a

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : /Users/ashfaq/Library/Android/sdk/

Comment: did you have any logs from the device?

Comment: I dont see any errors in the logs. But I found out that platform ready event is not getting called and thus splash screen never hides

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Nope, i didn't find any solution

Answer (score 1):

please try this :

1. In xCode File > Workspace Settings > Build System : Legacy Build System
2. In Signing Team, be sur to use Team and provisioning Profile with developer capability (Debug) and not for production (Realse)